# conditional probability of a union

Tags: probability

A patient would like to take a test to determine if he has a nasty disease. Let the variable A denote that
the patient has the disease and the variable B denote a positive test. The following assumptions apply:
• The probability that the test is positive given the patient has the disease is 99%.
• The probability that the test is positive given the patient does not have the disease is 5%.
• The rate of occurrence of the disease in the general population is 0.1%.

Consider a second test for the same disease. A positive result for this test is denoted by C. The following
assumptions apply:
• The probability that the test is positive given the patient has the disease is 80%.
• The probability that the test is positive given the patient does not have the disease is 0.01%.

Now that both tests have been taken, assume conditional independence of these tests.
Both tests give a positive answer. What is the probability that the patient has the disease?

so my question is do i apply P(A|BnC) ?if so how do i deduce this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let us summarise the information we are given:-
$$P(A)=0.001\Rightarrow P(\overline{A})=1-P(A)=0.999$$
For the first test:-
$$P(B|A)=0.99$$
$$P(B|\overline{A})=0.05$$
For the second test:-
$$P(C|A)=0.8$$
$$P(C|\overline{A})=0.0001$$

In order to calculate $P(A|B,C)$, let us invoke Bayes' Rule:-
$$P(A|B,C)=\frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(B,C)}=\frac{P(B,C|A)P(A)}{P(B,C|A)P(A)+P(B,C|\overline{A})P(\overline{A})}$$
We are told that the tests are conditionally independent given the disease status of the patient (highlighted in blue, below), so that
$$\begin{align}
P(A|B,C)&=\frac{\color{blue}{P(B|A)P(C|A)}P(A)}{\color{blue}{P(B|A)P(C|A)}P(A)+\color{blue}{P(B|\overline{A})P(C|\overline{A}})P(\overline{A})}\\&=\frac{0.99\times0.8\times0.001}{(0.99\times0.8\times0.001)+(0.05\times0.0001\times0.999)}\\&=0.99373\approx99.4\%\end{align}$$

Comment: does P(B,C) == P(BnC) and if the events are conditionally independent is P(BnC) = P(B)*P(C) , if i use this as the denominator i get a different result to yours. How did you get your denominator, does it mean A and B are conditionally independent on A, but not on each other so P(BnC) != P(B)*P(C)

Comment: If the tests are conditionally independent, it means that given $A$,tests $B$ and $C$ are independent of each other i.e. $P(B,C|A)=P(B|A)P(C|A)$. In general, conditional independence does not imply marginal independence where $P(B,C)=P(B)P(C)$.

Comment: Thanks Alijah, i tried to contact you via your blog but got no response. What is the best way to get in touch i have some other related thing we need to discuss

Comment: @DrManhattan - I have just replied to you via the blog, and it would be preferable to communicate through there instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want $P(A | B \cup C)$, you want $P(A | B \cap C)$. Here are some hints:

By the definition of conditional probability, and then by independence:

$$P(A | B \cap C) = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(B \cap C)} = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(B)P(C)}.$$

The numbers that you have are

$P(A) = .001$, $P(B |A) = 0.99$, $P(B | \overline{A}) = .05$, $P(C|A) = 0.8$, $P(C|\overline{A}) = 0.0001$.

Use the definitions of conditional probability. Try to take it from here.

Comment: Many thanks for sending me in the right direction, sorry i couldnt upvote because my reputation is still low